# What is the most efficient way to save a big graphic?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, export, memory

I want to generate a graphic using

```
DiscretePlot[primePercent[x], {x, 10^10}, 
  ImageSize -> Full, 
  Filling -> None, 
  Joined -> True]
```

where

```
primePercent[x_Integer] := 100 PrimePi[x]/x
```

When I generate it for 10^6, my computer becomes slow as there are simply too many data points. What I'm wondering is if I can get some load off my RAM by continually saving the evaluated data to a file (or using a different evaluation method/graphic options, of course)?

Does `Export[]` save the file only once it has been generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a nice plot you don't need all the million points in your graphic. `10^10` points is a bit heavy for this curve, so why not using `Plot`? It has the advantage of adaptive sampling and it seems to do it absolutely correct in this case. The runtime is only about 1 second:

```
Plot[100 PrimePi[x]/x, {x, 1, 10^10}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}]
```

[image]

And even if you reduce your range, it catches all features

```
Plot[100 PrimePi[x]/x, {x, 1, 50}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Update on *Accuracy***

In the comment you asked how accurate this is. I assume you mean "are there enough points in the plot to represent important features?" Consider the following `Manipulate` where you can visually inspect the sampling points in your plot with different settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[100 PrimePi[x]/x, {x, 1, xEnd}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.005], Red], 
  MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion, PlotPoints -> plotPoints, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 {xEnd, 10, 1000}, {maxRecursion, 0, 5, 1}, {plotPoints, 5, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

Basically those options work like that: `PlotPoints` defines how many sampling points are in your region initially. With the `MaxRecursion` setting `Plot` has the opportunity to subdivide the region at places where the function is not represented properly. This can be deduced by some curvature measure, but what exactly Mathematica is using for this decision is afaik not documented.

Therefore, `MaxRecursion` is more important to catch features than many `PlotPoints` alone. On the other hand when you want a plot from `1` to `10^10` than you are clearly more interested in the overall *tendency* of the function than in the structure of the sharp edges between `4` and `10`, which couln't be displayed anyway.

So when you are asking about accuracy, I'm not really sure what to answer. Every (red) point you see above is as accurate as it would be in `DiscretePlot` and usually the default settings for `Plot` work nicely and catch most features you want to see. But to have a feeling for that you can now use the `Manipulate` and watch what happens.

In return I could ask, in your `DiscretePlot` do you see the difference between point `10^5` and point `10^5+1`? Or is this maybe the wrong scale and you are more interested in the global bend from `0` to `2*10^9`, because then you could leave out many points and exactly this is, what `Plot` tries to do.

Comment: That is unimaginably faster. Thanks. How accurate is it, though?

Comment: @CHM I updated my post.

Comment: Great. The `Manipulate` helped. My concern was if `Plot` would too much approximation, but of course this can be dealt with by tweaking the options. Thanks.

Comment: @halirutan would you please join me in chat if you are here.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that 10^10 points is an outrageously large amount of computation no matter what hoops you jump through. Even something much more modest, say 10^7 points, is going to eat up your RAM when using any `Graphics` object to store it all in.

I suggest creating a series of rasterized images and using some basic image processing to join them together. The following code does that, though I warn you, it is slow.  The plus side is that it won't run you out of memory!

```
primePercent[x_Integer] := 100 PrimePi[x]/x
```

Here `step`, `max`, and `isize` are the number of points to plot in intermediate images, the total number of desired points, and the image size respectively.

```
step = 10^5;
max = 10^7;
isize = 500;
```

I store an initial image `img0`.

```
img0 = Rasterize[
   DiscretePlot[primePercent[k], {k, step}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, max}, {0, 60}}, ImageSize -> Full, 
    Filling -> None, Joined -> True], ImageSize -> isize];
```

Here, I set up a dynamic progress indicator.  Its nice to know how long you have to wait if you are going to be waiting a while!

```
Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[(i/max)]]
```

This is where I put it all together. I'm using `ImageMultiply` to combine rasterized images. This will overemphasize repeated components which is why `AxesStyle` is set to 0 opacity.

```
Do[img0 = 
  ImageMultiply[img0, 
   Rasterize[
    DiscretePlot[primePercent[k], {k, i - step + 1, i}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, max}, {0, 60}}, ImageSize -> Full, 
     Filling -> None, Joined -> True, 
     AxesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]]], ImageSize -> isize]]
     , {i, 2 step, max, step}
]
```

The resulting image looks like...

[image]

The easiest first step to getting a higher quality image would be to set `isize` to something larger.

**Edit:** As David points out in his response, it is better for this particular example to specify a step size in `DiscretePlot`.  Only use the method I've provided if David's approach isn't reasonable for your particular application.

Answer (score 4):

Have you already tried `Export["picture.png", DiscretePlot[100 PrimePi[k]/k, {k, 10^10}, ImageSize -> Full, Filling -> None, Joined -> True]]`? This directly saves to a file instead of you having to wait for the front end to display the image in addition to the computational effort expended by evaluating your function.

Comment: I did. It works up to a point (10^6) well. after that, good luck. :/

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, you don't want to have all the $10^{11}$ data points `DiscretePlot` generated. Luckily, there's an option for that: Instead of specifying `{x, 10^11}` like you did, there's an optional parameter dealing with the step size the plot uses. The bracket is actually of the form `{x, xMin, xMax, dx}`, where `dx` is the step width to be taken, just like for example in the `Table` function.

Benchmark:

```
AbsoluteTiming@DiscretePlot[
    100 PrimePi[x]/x,
    {x, 1, 10^11, 10^9},
    ImageSize -> 600,
    Filling -> None,
    Joined -> True
]
```

> [image]

Way better, isn't it? 100 points are easier to plot than 100 billion ;-)

A shortcoming here is that `DiscretePlot` does not provide adaptive sampling, i.e. automatically generates denser point sets where the data fluctuates. This is something you'll have to take care of on your own somehow.

Comment: This is also very fast. I think the slowest function is `PrimePi`: both your method and halirutan's are very quick up to 10^11. Once you get to 10^12, evaluation time takes long enough for me not to bother evaluating it. As this is only for a qualitative purpose, I don't mind not having 10^12.